# Newly installed magento error on Call to a member function setParent() - nginx

Tags: magento

Newly Installed Magento not working because of the following error. i'm using php5-fpm and nginx.

Searching the web shows that the error probably has a problem with php-dom and simplexml, i already re-installed them and updated to the latest version but the site still does not work.

I never seen the front page and backend after the installation wizard completed.

TIA

```
 013/07/26 23:02:09 [error] 870#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setParent() on a non-object in /var/www/staging.site.com/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 440
    PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
    PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/staging.site.com/index.php:0
    PHP message: PHP   2. Mage::run() /var/www/staging.site.com/index.php:87
    PHP message: PHP   3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /var/www/staging.site.com/app/Mage.php:683
    PHP message: PHP   4. Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules() /var/www/staging.site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:343
    PHP message: PHP   5. Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadDb() /var/www/staging.site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:420
    PHP message: PHP   6. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Config->loadToXml() /var/www/staging.site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:354
    PHP message: PHP   7. Varien_Simplexml_Element->extend() /var/www/staging.site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Config.php:112
    PHP message: PHP   8. Varien_Simplexml_Element->extendChild() /var/www/staging.site.com/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php:387" while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.198.90.162, server: staging.site.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "staging.site.com"
```

Comment: Did you change any `xml` files before the installation? Also, which operating system you using? Because, `setParent()` method calling once more before line 440.

Comment: No i am not changing any xml, i just extracted the tarball  and installed it. whenever i check the home page and admin that error occurs